# How can I get the screen reader to read controls that are not tab stops (e.g. static labels)?

Tags: accessibility, winrt-xaml

I would like for screen readers (Narrator, JAWS, NVDA) to read aloud the text of certain labels on my WinRT/C++ WinUI3 XAML-based windows, so that the sight-impaired user can know the context of the window that they have in the foreground.

I would rather not make these controls a tab stop, since most people will not be using a screen reader, and would not expect the tab control to stop there.

I have been unable to find anything that works so far, and I am thinking I may need to resort to setting the `AutomationProperties.Name` of the top-level window itself to the text I want read aloud.

Any tips/tricks/pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please tell us what your project is? UWP? WinForms or others?

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT It's WinRT/C++ and WinUI3

Comment: What do you want to read aloud? Could you please explain it in detail? Is it the header of the [tab view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/tab-view)?

Comment: Is it possible that you are unfamiliar with the usage of a screen reader? Tab navigation is but one means of navigation, known as forms or focus mode. I’m more involved in web apps, but I believe even on desktop you can simply read contents in browse mode with the arrow keys. Here’s [the shortcuts for NVDA.](https://www.nvaccess.org/files/nvdaTracAttachments/455/keycommands%20with%20laptop%20keyboard%20layout.html#8) Which screen reader are you using?

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT They are <TextBlock> elements within a <Page> -> <StackPanel> -> <Grid>. Andy I am certain that I am unfamiliar with screen readers... I am trying to use Narrator in Windows 11, and haven't dug into the settings/key shortcuts. Perhaps I should start with that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible ways here.

1.Turn on the narrator's mouse mode.
[image]

2.Use [AutomationProperties.LabeledBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.automation.automationproperties.labeledby?view=winrt-22621) to bind Textblock.

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock x:Name="TitleText" Text="please enter your name"  AutomationProperties.AutomationId="id" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <TextBox Width="200" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" AutomationProperties.LabeledBy="{Binding ElementName=TitleText}"/>
        <Button Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: This is about the best answer I've seen yet on the 'tubes. I accidentally figured this out on my own last night, my method was slightly different: I enabled that mouse mode, and `"scan mode."` Then I used `AutomationProperties.Name` in the XAML. Thanks for the help!